# Reallocated Sector Count - is drive failure really imminent?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, laptop, smart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if Disk Utility shows bad sectors pending in SMART?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159829/what-to-do-if-disk-utility-shows-bad-sectors-pending-in-smart)

I just recently installed Ubuntu (latest version) alongwise my Windows XP. First, after trying the Live CD, it was giving me messages about hard disk failure.

I decided to go ahead and dual boot with my Windows XP. The first problem that I had was that it didn't give me the option to install alongside Windows XP, and the "Something Else" wasn't very helpful in manually having to define my own partitions. I restarted my computer and tried again, and still didn't show it.

I left for an hour or so and came back and restarted again. This time, it did show the option to install alongisde windows, so I did it, leaving 20 GB on my Windows Partition and 40 GB on my ubuntu partition.

I still get popups often about the disk failure thing. In SMART Data it says this:

Reallocated Sector Count
Normalized: 134
Worst: 134
Threshhold: 140
Value: 526 Sectors

Failing

Now, I've never had problems with this in Windows. Could this possibly be an error? My computer is a Dell Latitude D630 laptop computer. Can I still use the laptop as normal?